# Easiest way to sort on an array of strings in the date format of 'Year-Month-Day T Hour-Minute - Seconds Z'

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

So I have an array of dates in the the format in the title, for example:

```
const dates = ["2014-13-01T13:81:00.862279Z", "2009-10-04T11:21:00.8322170Z", ...];
```

Whats the best/ correct way to get the earliest and latest date?

I can see theres obvious, yet unduly long ways to sort on each segment of each date, but I was wondering if there was an inbuilt date function in JavaScript which could do this natively.

I don't wish to import any libraries, such as Moment.js.

Comment: The title is unclear; you're sorting an array of date *formats*?  Or an array of *dates*?  The code in the question isn't valid JS.  Are those supposed to be strings?

Comment: Updated to clarify I'm sorting on strings of date formats :)

Comment: ISO 8601 date strings sort lexically, so just sort them. Once sorted, the smallest will be at index 0 and the largest at index `length - 1` (assuming the array isn't sparse of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the array and use a string comparison for getting the smallest or greatest [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) in a single loop.

```
[earliest, latest] = arrayOfISOStrings.reduce((r, iso, i) => {
    if (!i) return [iso, iso];
    if (iso < r[0]) r[0] = iso;
    if (iso > r[1]) r[1] = iso;
    return r;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are sorting string and your format goes from the Year month day, Hour minutes seconds, you can use the built in sort function. However if the format is different then this won't be the best choice

```
dates.sort()
```

```js
const dates = ["2014-13-01T13:81:00.862279Z", "2009-10-04T11:21:00.8322170Z", "2009-10-05T11:21:00.8322170Z", "2009-10-04T11:21:00.8422170Z"];
console.log(dates.sort());
```